# PHP- File download without using file_get_contents method

Tags: php

What i need to know is how to  download a file which is stored in a path. Is it necessary to store the contents in the DB? When i referred another site it gave me a solution in which  the content of the file is stored in db using **file_get_content** method and through that it is downloading the file.Is there another way? i have checked without using the method but the contents are not displaying even though download occurs.

Comment: Try [readfile](http://us3.php.net/readfile) instead.

Comment: I don't see the connection between "in the db" and "file_get_contents". please tell why you can't use file_get_contents, on account of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: `file_get_contents` doesn't put anything in a database.

Comment: @Midhun do not *not* ***NOT*** store video files in a database! Are you crazy? Store it in the filesystem and store the *path to it* in the database.

Comment: That's what i need to know. How can i download a file which is stored in a path. Is it necessary to store the contents in the DB? When i referred  another site it was given in a way like its stores the content of the file in db using file_get_content and through that it is downloading the file.Is there another way? i have checked without using the method but the contents are not displaying even though download occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two opstions:

**1. Store the file in a database**
In order to do this, you will need to read the contents of the file into memory and then store it in the database. `file_get_contents()` is the logical choice for reading the file in order to store it in the database.

**pros**: easier. **cons**: worse performance and managability when dataset becomse large.
**recommended for**: small files `&&` simpel projects.

**2. Store the file on disk**
The alternative option is to store the file on disk and store the path-to-the-file in your database. The best method to get the file from disk and send it to the client is `readfile()`; it reads from disk and streams the contents directly to the browser.

**pros**: Better scalability (all *large* websites use this method). **cons**: more complex.
**recommended for**: large files `||` larger projects.

Answer (score 1):

Once the file is on the server you can stop saying "download". The proper terminology is now to "read the file".

Honestly, `file_get_contents()` is the best option if you just need to read an entire file into a variable and then do stuff with it. It is *intended* to be used on local files, but people like to use it to get remote files as well. [those people are *wrong* IMHO. :P]

If you're hell bent on using something else there's always [`fread()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php), or using a loop with [`fgets()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).